# AddThis + iOS + Facebook crash

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, addthis

I'm using AddThis within iOS to share an image. Although everything else works (Twitter, email, etc.), as I try to share the image with Facebook, the application crashes. I setup the FB keys and secret as required, but after some debugging, this is the error that comes up:

```
[FBRequest initWithSession:graphPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x268b10
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, the problem is solved!

I was able to solve it by removing every Facebook file inside the folder ThirdPartyLibs/FBConnect except for the folder FacebookSDK. The problem was that the code inside this folder (ThirdPartyLibs/FBConnect) was "hiding" the valid code inside the FacebookSDK folder and there was a repeated FBRequest header that did not have initWithSession:graphPath:

I hope that this might help anyone that runs into the same issue. ;)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but because of the presence of MCShareKit. The problem is...if I remove the FB classes inside of the ShareKit folder, ShareKit will then use the latest FB framework that I included in the app...which might be incompatible with the version it needs. So, how to solve?

Comment: @Sagito: My app crashes also. But it crashes as soon as I use [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init]. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi @Carnal, which version of the FB SDK are you using?

Comment: @Sagito: Hey mate, I solved my issue. I had the same name of my own "FBRequest", as soon as I renamed it, it worked! (Conflict with the real one). Thanks anyway mate :)